How to make these changes in circuitikz?
I have the following example circuiTikz code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}        
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.75]
        % Paths, nodes and wires:
        \draw (10.75, 4.5) to[american resistor, l_={$100\scriptsize\Omega$}, label distance=0.02cm] (9, 4.5);
        \draw (10.75, 4.5) to[capacitor, l={$10\scriptsize mF$}, label distance=0.02cm] (10.75, 3);
        \draw (7.5, 4.5) to[american controlled current source, l={$1.5\cdot v_1$}, label distance=0.02cm] (9, 4.5);
        \draw (9, 4.5) to[american voltage source, l={$20\tiny V$}, label distance=-0.03cm] (9, 3);
        \draw[draw] (7.5, 4.5) -| (7.5, 3);
        \draw[draw] (7.5, 3) -- (9, 3);
        \draw[draw] (9, 3) -- (10.75, 3);
        \draw (6, 3) to[american voltage source, l={$V_s$}, label distance=0.08cm] (6, 4.5);
        \draw (6, 4.5) to[cute inductor, l={$15\scriptsize\mu H$}, label distance=0.02cm] (7.5, 4.5);
        \draw[draw] (6, 3) -- (7.5, 3);
        \draw node[ground] at (8.5, 3) {};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}

which results in the following image (without the marker in magenta of course)

I want to add to the circuit the small i_x with the arrowhead pointing left after the inductor, and the v_1 with the "+" and "-" symbols beside it, how can I do it?

Your MWE works by accident. Since you use elements from circuitikz package, you should use circuitikz environment. Than you should make yourself more familiar with package. It has excellent documentation. Yes, it is not short (since package define bunch of elements and describe their use and customization), but it is worth to read thoroughly. For current $i_x$ try to add to inductance the option i^>=$i_x$ . For  voltage is usually used option v=$v_1$, but for what you are after about it, you should wait on an answer (temporally I haven't time). BTW, in your code is quite easy to lost.

@Zarko - circuitikz is tikzpicture, as in \let\circuitikz=\tikzpicture and \let\endcircuitikz=\endtikzpicture.

@JohnKormylo,you are right (I know this), but someone can unmistakably thing that circuitikz is compatible with tikz libraries for drawing of circuits.

Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see How do you accept an answer?). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Please use siunitx for units. You have a series of  Command \scriptsize invalid in math mode you are ignoring, and moreover, units must be in upright text, never italic.
The labels are each one at a different distance, mainly because the default ones are probably confused by the scale factor.
Anyway:
\draw (10.75, 4.5) to[american resistor, l_={$100\scriptsize\Omega$}, label distance=0.02cm, v^=$V_1$, american voltages] (9, 4.5);

and
\draw (6, 4.5) to[cute inductor, l={$15\scriptsize\mu H$}, label distance=0.02cm, i=$i_x$] (7.5, 4.5);

As explained in the chapter "voltages and currents" of the manual, gives:

These are the minimum changes (but please avoid the scale; this makes all distance calculations of circuitikz flaky, especially the voltage...) that I would do:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{american, raised voltages}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.75]
    % Paths, nodes and wires:
    \draw (10.75, 4.5) to[american resistor, l_=\qty{100}{\ohm}, v^<=$v_1$, voltage shift=-0.9] (9, 4.5);
    \draw (10.75, 4.5) to[capacitor, l=\qty{10}{\mF}] (10.75, 3);
    \draw (7.5, 4.5) to[american controlled current source, l=$1.5 v_1$] (9, 4.5);
    \draw (9, 4.5) to[american voltage source, l=\qty{20}{\V}] (9, 3);
    \draw[draw] (7.5, 4.5) -| (7.5, 3);
    \draw[draw] (7.5, 3) -- (9, 3);
    \draw[draw] (9, 3) -- (10.75, 3);
    \draw (6, 3) to[american voltage source, l={$V_s$}] (6, 4.5);
    \draw (6, 4.5) to[cute inductor, l=\qty{15}{\uH}, i=$i_x$] (7.5, 4.5);
    \draw[draw] (6, 3) -- (7.5, 3);
    \draw node[ground] at (8.5, 3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


To add a bit more, after reading your comment: one of the problems with using a graphical interface is that most of them (at least for now) build the circuit using separate components and lines, not by describing a logical path, like the @Zarko example does. It could be a minor thing, but look at your (or mine) circuit at 1600%:

...and Zarko's one:

See? In general, using TikZ (and so circuitikz), let's say "programmatically" over using a graphical interface, has the same advantage that using LaTeX over a WYSIWYG word processor has: it enables you to describe the semantic of the thing instead of only focusing on the appearance. Which, in turn, if correctly done, can lead to better outcomes even in appearance.

I see, thanks for the detailed response, I'll try and do as your other comment suggested, thanks!

Spelling out of my comment, now as supplement to @rmano answer (+1):
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}        
     \begin{circuitikz}[american]    % <---
\ctikzset{capacitors/width=0.1, capacitors/height=0.5}
\draw   (0,0)   coordinate (a)
                to[V=$V_s$]             ++ (0,2)
                to[L=15<\mu\henry>, 
                     i^>=$i_x$,-*]      ++ (3,0)    coordinate (b) % <---
                to[american controlled current source,
                   l=$1.5v_1$,-*]        ++ (2,0)    coordinate (c)
                to[R=100<\ohm>,
                     v=$V_s$]        ++ (3,0)
                to[C=10<\micro\farad>]  ++ (0,-2)
                -- (a);
\draw   (b)     to[short, -*]       (b |-a)
        (c)     [V=20<\volt>, -*]   (c |- a)
        ($(b |-a)!0.5!(c |-a)$)  to [short, -*] ++ (0,0) node[ground] {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}



I don't know why alias cisourceAM for american controlled current source doesn't work. Maybe will package author @rmano explain, what I miss/doing wrong if I in my MWE replace  american controlled current source with  cisourceAM.

nice implementation. The cisourceAM seems a bug, I'll look into it.

@Rmano, thank you in advance. I have the same feeling about the  cisourceAM.

https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/831

@Zarko your code looks so simple! I generated the code in this question using circuitTikZ Designer, since I don't have time to read all of the relevant documentation to understand how to position and do things as simply as you, did it take you long to learn how to generate circuits like this? or if you have a specified recommended source to learn how to do it like you, I would greatly appreciate it.

@Nate3384, thank you very much for nice words. Well, I still learning circuitikz . Also your question encouraged me to check my barn of interesting questions/answers about use of the circuitikz and read the package's documentation again ... In average I draw using circuitikz package about three electrical schemas per month (some month more, many months no one) . It is worth to repeat all examples in documentation and try to understand a way how they are drawn.

Zarko: well said. I added a bit of info to my answer. @Nate3384, if you want to learn, I suggest starting with the first tutorial in Tikz and then going through the ones in circuitikz.

@Rmano, as you explained in your edited answer,  how some on-line service for drawing works, is main reason why I do not trust to them . Maybe ones, when those tools will be well supported with AI .
